# initrd.lz lzma extract error

Tags: extract

i am trying to extract the initrd.lz from the casper folder

```
lzma -dc -S .lz initrd.lz | cpio -imvd --no-absolute-filenames
```

and i get this message:

```
lzma: Decoder error
cpio: premature end of archive
```

i am using ubuntu 10.10, is there another command to extract lz files? am i missing a parameter?

what can be the issue? thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will see this error if you are :

1. Using a different distribution other than Ubuntu (for example [Mint](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=198&t=85977)) OR
2. you have an old version of Ubuntu (eg: [Karmic 9.10](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+question/89310)) OR
3. you have a disk error OR
4. you are trying using a software like [Reconstructor](https://code.lumentica.com/boards/1/topics/144)

If you want to customize your initrd, i recommend to use the latest version 11.10 and then customize it.

Comment: oh i was using mint11 file with ubuntu 11.10 it works, thanks